# MYSQL order results beofre grouping to return the newest record

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have this database:
[image]

and I want the get the latest position of each driver with one query

[image]
My query

```
select d.id, d.names, d.phone, d.vehicle, d.platenumber, dp.lat, dp.lng, MAX(dp.added_date) as added_date 
from drivers d, 
(SELECT * FROM driver_positions ORDER BY added_date DESC) as dp 
where d.id = dp.driver_id and d.status = "1" and DATE(added_date) = DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY d.id order by dp.added_date ASC
```

works, but returns only one result for 1 driver, but not as expected list:

1. Driver_id 5 / record 3 and its lat && lng
2. Driver_id 6 / record 5 and its lat && lng
3. Driver_id 7 / record 7 and its lat && lng

Is it possible to get the correct info with 1 query or I will have to loop..

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You're only getting one row because you forgot `GROUP BY`.

Comment: #Barmar, i just edited the query and added GROUP BY d.id and now it returns 3 records (very well) but the lat & long are wrong.. What could cause this? Thanks

Comment: That wasn't your only problem, it was just the reason why you only got one row. Did you go to the linked question and see how to do it properly?

Comment: No, just saw it and going to read ! :)

Comment: #Barmar, I could not succeed to change the example to my case.. It returns errors.. Please have a look at this changed query: 
SELECT d.id, d.names, d.phone, d.vehicle, d.platenumber
FROM drivers d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT lat, lng, MAX(added_date) ad 
    FROM driver_positions 
    GROUP BY driver_id
) dp ON d.id = dp.driver_id 
it returns error Unknown column 'dp.driver_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: The subquery needs to be `SELECT driver_id, lat, lng, ...`

Comment: It also doesn't need `lat, lng`, it should just be `SELECT drive_id, MAX(added_date) ad FROM ...`

Comment: Well, I changed it to:

SELECT d.id, d.names, d.phone, d.vehicle, d.platenumber, dp.lat, dp.lng  
FROM drivers d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT driver_id, MAX(added_date) ad   
    FROM driver_positions 
    GROUP BY driver_id
) dp ON d.id = dp.driver_id but returns Unknown column 'dp.lat' in 'field list'

Comment: if I remove dp.lat and dp.lng works, but how to get lat && lng than?

Comment: You should use `d.lat`, `d.lng`. You can just use `d.*` to get everything.

Comment: #Barmar the query SELECT d.* FROM drivers d INNER JOIN ( SELECT driver_id, MAX(added_date) ad, lat, lng FROM driver_positions GROUP BY driver_id ) dp ON d.id = dp.driver_id order by ad ASC works but still lat, lng are not shown

Comment: You're missing a join. You need to join `driver_positions` with the subquery that gets the `MAX(added_date)`, to get the row of that table with the highest date. Didn't you see that in the linked question?

Comment: `SELECT dp.* FROM driver_positions dp JOIN (SELECT driver_id, MAX(added_date) ad GROUP by driver_id) max_dp ON dp.driver_id = max_dp.driver_id AND dp.added_date = max_dp.ad`

Comment: Then you join that with `driver` to add the `driver` columns.

Comment: #Barmar your query doesn't work whatever I change.. returns different errors .. anyway, thank you for your time

Comment: If you add your latest attempt to the question, I'll reopen and answer.

Comment: #Barmar I just added the second table structure - maybe now is more clear what I am trying to get as results :)

Comment: I asked you to add your query that's not working, so I can see what you're doing wrong and show how to fix it.

Comment: I just tested your latest query SELECT dp.* FROM driver_positions dp JOIN (SELECT driver_id, MAX(added_date) ad GROUP by driver_id) max_dp ON dp.driver_id = max_dp.driver_id AND dp.added_date = max_dp.ad and it returned error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP by driver_id) max_dp ON dp.driver_id = max_dp.driver_id AND dp.added_date ' at line 1

Comment: I asked you to add it to the question. Code in comments has no formatting and is hard to read.

Comment: You're missing `FROM driver_position` in the subquery.

Comment: `SELECT dp.* FROM driver_positions dp JOIN (SELECT driver_id, MAX(added_date) ad FROM driver_positions GROUP by driver_id) max_dp ON dp.driver_id = max_dp.driver_id AND dp.added_date = max_dp.ad`

Comment: Barmar, I don't see table drivers to be connected in the query, how it is supposed to show the drivers names, phone and etc.. :) You use twice the same table driver_positions

Comment: Yes, to get the latest row from driver_position you have to join the table with itself. You can then add another join with `driver` to get that information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191598/discussion-between-europeuser-and-barmar).